# Is there way to completion time and how much processing is over for Amazon Elastic Transcoder job

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I try to transcode some movie with Elastic Transcoder and while the job processing, I wanna display on the screen

- Completion time (ex. complete around in 40 seconds)
- How much processing job over (ex. 75%)

Is there way to know with some api related transcoded api or using some tool ?

I can know the job status (completed, processing) with job API, and with Amazon SNS you can receive notification when the job is over .
But what I wanna know is not in some document, any idea ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ask a technical support for AWS,

Accourding to the answer, 
You cannot know complete time with some aws tool, but how much processing job over you can with MediaCovert in AWS services .